# ODBC PDO Select Query LIKE Clause not working in PHP 7

Tags: php, pdo, odbc

I'm having a hard time to show results from my query using a PDO Like clause.

I have two database, One from Wampp Server and the other is from MS SQL.

For the MS SQL I used a connection like this:

```
$connection = new PDO('odbc:Driver={SQL Server};Server=Server\SQL2008;Database=dbname; Uid=hr;Pwd=hrpassword');
```

I tried to `select` all fields using a simple `PDO SELECT` query and it worked fine 
Just to give an idea of the table, here is the table structure.

```
Table: CheckInOut
Columns: UserID, CheckTime, CheckType
```

Now, I'm trying to select all data using a `LIKE` clause to get all `CheckTime` that starts with 2020.

I tried using this PDO Select Query:

```
$keyword = "2020-01-01%";
// Prepare the command
$sth = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM CheckInOut WHERE CheckTime LIKE :keyword");
// Put the percentage sing on the keyword
$keyword = $keyword;
// // Bind the parameter
$sth->bindParam(':keyword', $keyword, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$sth->execute();
while ($s=$sth->fetch()) {
    echo $s['CheckTime']."<br/>";
}
```

It returns nothing. No error, No output so I cannot find what's wrong.
But If I tried using a `equals` clause instead of `LIKE`, It's working fine.

Code I used for the `equals` clause:

```
$keyword = "108";
// Prepare the command
$sth = $connection->prepare("SELECT CheckTime as CheckTime FROM CheckInOut WHERE UserID = :keyword");
// Put the percentage sing on the keyword
$keyword = $keyword;
// Bind the parameter
$sth->bindParam(':keyword', $keyword, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$sth->execute();

while ($s=$sth->fetch()) {
    echo $s['CheckTime']."<br/>";
}
```

Comment: Should the `keyword` have a `%` on both sides, not just the right?

Comment: @PaulT. I put the `%` at end because I want to find dates that starts with `2020-01-01`. I tried putting `%` both sides but it's still the same, no output

Comment: Ok, wanted to make sure not a typo.

Comment: Can you please add the code for the `equals` that works? Just want to see if it parameterized as well and what the value is. (`$keyword = $keyword;` also is not needed).

Comment: @user3783243 hello, i've added the code below. thank you

Comment: a couple of things I noted about your code samples: 1) `$keyword = $keyword;` doesn’t add a percent sign; it does absolutely nothing, and 2) you’re comparing apples and oranges— you’re using two different fields. I’d dare say it’s not `like` vs `=`, it’s your checkTime field that’s wonky.